# Denied a B2-Visa to USA, will i be able to apply for ESTA?

Tags: visas, usa, visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas

I got denied for a nonimmigrant B2-Visa in 2017 for being unprepared for the interview and not enough proof of my life living

I know that I have to reapply for a new visa and get approved to visit the US

But my question is will I be able to apply for an ESTA anytime in the future when I want to visit the US again after the visa has expired?

Comment: AFger which visa has expired?

Comment: What’s your citizenship? If you needed a visa, you most probably aren’t eligible for the VWP anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're from a VWP country, you're still eligible to *apply* for an ESTA: being previously refused a visa doesn't make you inadmissible.

That said, you will be asked on the application form about whether you've ever been refused a visa, and it's [highly likely that the ESTA will be denied](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1097/~/previously-denied-a-visa-or-immigration-benefit):

> If you were previously denied a visa, or previously refused entry to the United States, or previously removed from the U.S., your ESTA application will most likely be denied.

If an ESTA is refused they refund $10 of the $14 application fee, so it doesn't hurt to try for $4, but I imagine it's unlikely to be approved.